# Add 'Show Package Contents' destination as a folder in Finder sidebar

Tags: finder, sidebar

You can right-click on some items in Finder and view it like it's a folder using 'Show Package Contents'.

Is there a way to add such a location in the sidebar?

I've tried dragging the file itself, but that just creates a sidebar shortcut that the OS doesn't know how to open.

Update: Here is an image of the 2 steps I take. There is no Contents folder.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Drag the top folder called 'Contents' to the Sidebar.

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately there is no Contents folder that I can tell. I updated my question to include what I see

Comment: You're going to have to pick a folder. You can only drop a folder [or partition] to the sidebar, not an app or 'document', even if it's a bundle [e.g. your Photos Library]